# Assign Specific Values to Matplotlib graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two values in a numpy array. 0,1.  I want to ensure 1 is always black and 0 is always grey when I graph the array.

How can I do this in matplotlib?

Thank you

Comment: Which kind of plot do you want to use? Please also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to plot an image plot (`plt.imshow()`), you can select a colormap like "gray_r" which has white as lowest and black as highest color, gray will be in the middle. If you now normalize the image plot to values between -1 and 1, the array's 0 value will correspond to the middle of the colormap (being gray) and 1 will correspond to the upper end of the colormap (being black).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)

a = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(12,25))

plt.imshow(a, cmap="gray_r", vmin=-1, vmax=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]